# Pasar consulta de sql a laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Soy un tanto nuevo en Laravel, tengo esta consulta en sql y quiero pasar a laravel

```
Select users_groups.Name
FROM tm_employee
INNER JOIN users ON tm_employee.UserId = users.id
INNER JOIN users_groups ON users.groupId = users_groups.id
WHERE tm_employee.id = $variable
```

Estoy trabajando con los modelos User, userGroup, employee

Comment: Hola, cual es tu inconveniente con aquella consulta!?

Comment: Lo que necesito con esa consulta es pasar a laravel, usando lo que llaman ELOQUENT y de lo que no tengo mucha practica

Comment: Hola gmrYaeL! ¿Estás usando el query builder o el ORM Eloquent?

Comment: Hola Matias Oliviera, estoy usando el ORM.

Comment: sería muy util si por ejemplo nos dices en que orden estan relacionadas estas tablas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder realizar consultas con Eloquent, es necesario definir las relaciones que existen entre los modelos agregando métodos en ambas clases. Existen diferentes tipos de relaciones: "uno a uno", "uno a muchos", "muchos a muchos", entre otras.

[Aprender más sobre las relaciones](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

El método `find` te permite obtener un un registro según su clave primaria. ["Obteniendo una instancia de un modelo"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

```
Select users_groups.Name
FROM tm_employee
WHERE tm_employee.id = $variable
```

es equivalente a

```
$user = App\User::find($userID);
```

*Devuelve el usuario que tiene el ID indicado.*

---

El método `with` permite obtener una o más relaciones en una única operación. Recibe un string con el nombre de la relación o un array de strings con los nombres de las relaciones que te interesan. [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
Select users_groups.Name
FROM tm_employee
INNER JOIN users ON tm_employee.UserId = users.id
INNER JOIN users_groups ON users.groupId = users_groups.id
```

es equivalente a

```
$users = App\User::with(['userGroup', 'employee'])->get();
```

*Devuelve el listado completo de usuarios incluyendo su grupo y sus datos como empleado.*

---

Utilizando ambos métodos, quedaría de esta manera en el controlador

```
$user = App\User::with(['userGroup', 'employee'])->find($userID);
```

Comment: esto solo funciona si tiene en uso las relaciones de Eloquent, pero  y si no?}

Comment: @shadow Se puede utilizar el constructor de consultas (query builder) o directamente ejecutar consultas SQL dependiendo de lo que se quiera hacer.

Comment: si eso lo se, a lo que voy; es que deberías añadir como es que deben estar declaradas las relaciones en Eloquent

Comment: @shadow Si, me lo imaginaba, solo lo comente para que quede como referencia por si alguien tiene esa duda en el futuro. Voy a agregar una aclaración sobre ese punto, gracias por el feedback.